# WordPress Append a file to the_content

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I'd like to include a file to the end of the main content (the_content) but using my code below it is being added before the content. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

```
function add_listing_dashboard_content( $content ) {
    
    global $page_id_dashboard;    
    $page_id_dashboard = get_field('dashboard_page', 'option');   
  
    if (is_page($page_id_dashboard) && is_user_logged_in() ) :
        $content .include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-dashboard.php');
    endif; 
    
    return $content;
        
} 
add_action('the_content', 'add_listing_dashboard_content');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be the correct way of doing it:

```
function add_listing_dashboard_content( $content ) {
    
    global $post;

    ob_start();
    include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-dashboard.php');
    $append = ob_get_clean();

    $page_id_dashboard = get_field('dashboard_page', 'option');  
    if (is_page($page_id_dashboard) && is_user_logged_in() ) :
        $content.$append;
    endif; 
    
    return $content;
        
} 
add_action('the_content', 'add_listing_dashboard_content');
```

Check if it works.

*NOTE: I do not know if your get_field is retrieving correctly a page_id, instead for testing purposes remove the if and check if field is being included, then work on the conditions.*